# How do you delete unspecified users from a text file of wanted users?

Tags: users, user-management

Say I have a text file of users I want. How can I write a script or a code to delete all users except the users I specified in the text file?

Comment: Does your list include system users like root, nobody, etc.?

Comment: Read `man grep`, especially about the `--file=` and `--invert-match` options. This is easy.

Comment: It is risky to make a script for this task automatically. It is better to run some commands. that lists the candidates for removal, and then inspect and edit the list of candidates. Finally, you can use the edited list as input, when you remove the user IDs.

Answer (score 1):

let me offer a simple solution based on your limited information. I made two files:

1. name.txt:

   ```
   george
   koko
   victor
   bassey
   jane
   effiong
   ```
2. remove.txt:

   ```
   net
   paul
   garret
   jonah
   jane
   koko
   effiong
   ```

The steps would be:

1. use grep to only match names not in name.txt:

   ```
   grep --file=/path/to/name.txt -v /path/to/remove.txt
   ```

   - Result:

     ```
     net
     paul
     garret
     jonah
     ```
2. Then remove non-macthin names using `sed` command:

   ```
   grep --file=/path/to/name.txt -v /path/to/remove.txt | sed 's/$//g'
   ```

   - The above command will will not remove the names from the `remove.txt` but list them to the terminal, from here you can send the names to a new file or add the `-i` option in `sed` command to do the actuall name removal.